# RSpec routing test problems with params in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, param, nested-resources

i have a strange problem.. rspec generated a class named menus_routing_spec.rb in spec/routing

the tests are failing because menus is a nested resource of restaurant.

this is my test:

```
    describe MenusController do

  before :each do
    @restaurant = FactoryGirl.create(:random_restaurant)
    @menu = FactoryGirl.create(:menu)
  end

  describe 'routing' do
    it 'routes to #index' do
      params = {}
      params['restaurant_id'] = @restaurant


      #get('/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus').should route_to('menus#index')
      #get(restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)).should route_to('menus#index')
      #get(restaurant_menus_path, { :restaurant_id => @restaurant  }).should route_to('menus#index')

      get restaurant_menus_path, { :restaurant_id => @restaurant.to_param  }
      expect(response).should route_to('menus#index')
    end
```

the path in rake routing looks like this:

```
restaurant_menus_path    GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus(.:format)   menus#index
```

i get always this error message:

```
Failure/Error: get restaurant_menus_path, @restaurant.to_param
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"menus"} missing required keys: [:restaurant_id]
```

I tried also the other ones.. but same error..
does anyone can see where i am doing the mistake?

this is a test in spec/controllers/menus_controller_spec.rb which works fine

```
it 'renders the index template' do
      get :index, { :restaurant_id => @restaurant  }
      expect(response).to render_template('index')
    end
```

thank you very much for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Routing specs should test that the action (`get`) given a path as a string (i.e. "/first/1/second/2") will route to an action with the correct parameters set (i.e. `first_id: 1, id: 2`)

You don't need to create an instance of your models here. It's unnecessary and it'll just slow down the spec.

```
describe MenusController do
  describe 'routing' do
    it 'routes to #index' do
      get('/restaurants/42/menus').should route_to('menus#index', restaurant_id: 42)
    end

    it 'routes to #show' do
      get('/restaurants/42/menus/37').should route_to('menus#index', restaurant_id: 42, id: 37)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also pass in other arguments, like `format: :json`, or anything else that might be gleaned from a URL string, as it's mainly testing that your routes file directs you to the correct place with the correct parameters.

Comment: Hey Josh, thank you.. that seems to be a good way of doing it.. it is much cleaner.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. i solved it, but i am really not sure if this is the correct way.. if somebody has a different way to do it, please tell me :)

this worked for me:

```
it 'routes to #index with correct restaurant id' do
      {:get => restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)}.should route_to(:controller => 'menus', :action => 'index', :restaurant_id => @restaurant.to_param)
end

it 'routes not to #index with wrong restaurant id' do
      {:get => restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)}.should_not route_to(:controller => 'menus', :action => 'index', :restaurant_id => @restaurant1.to_param)
end
```